# Scraping multipage table using selenium and python

Tags: python, windows, web-scraping

I've to scrape a website of online airline booking.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver_win32_2\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

driver.get("https://matrix.itasoftware.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_id("cityPair-orig-0").send_keys("BOM")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("relative").click()
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.find_element_by_id("cityPair-dest-0").send_keys("AMS")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("relative").click()
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.find_element_by_id("cityPair-outDate-0").send_keys("01/01/2019")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("relative").click()
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.find_element_by_id("cityPair-outDate-0").send_keys("02/01/2019")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("relative").click()
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
search = driver.find_element_by_id("searchButton-0")

driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
search.click()
```

When I run the code then the website that I get is not similar to the actual website. The actual website contains a multipage table (17 pages) which is reduced to only 1 page when I run the code. Because of this, I'm not able to get the list of all the airlines after scraping.

[This is the actual website showing 17 pages at the bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRvPw.png)

[This I get after running the code. And it sums up all the 17 pages into 1 by skipping airlines in between. There are many airlines missing on the webpage that I get after scraping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDCFO.png)

Comment: I think this is deliberate when browser detected. There is a POST request made (this returns data in batches of 30 records where 1 parameter varies in the json posted (this corresponds with page number). All the info is in there but I only get internal server errors when I attempt POST.

Comment: When I tried the similar code on a different website today which also consists multipage table, the code ran successfully showing me the website similar to the actual website. Is there any possibility of some sort of restriction applied by website?

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying. I have come across travel websites before which limit to one page when bot detected. Makes sense in a way as you don't want competitors simply scraping your best deals.

Comment: Is there any solution for this? Because I need to scrap this website only!